# Using MFMailComposeViewController, is it possible to BCC the default mail account?

Tags: iphone, ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, bcc

I believe that the iOS SDK provides no access to the details of the default mail account (for good reason), but is there any other way to somehow setup MFMailComposeViewController to prefill the BCC field with the "from" address?

Am I overlooking something obvious or is the only way for the user to fill in the BCC herself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That information is not accessible via the public API.

Make them input their email on first launch? Perhaps search the Address Book for entries like "Me", or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

[`-[MFMailComposeViewController setBccRecipients:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008200-CH1-SW9)

Comment: I know how to set the the BCC recipients. What I can't figure out (if it is even possible) is how to set it to the same address the mail will be sent from -- i.e. the address of the default mail account on the phone.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for the app to do this itself.  However, MFMailComposeViewController will pre-fill the BCC field with the FROM address if the user has turned on the Mail setting for "Always Bcc Myself".